# Can't update sudo to latest version CVE-2021-3156

Tags: centos, sudo, yum

Due to latest CVE-2021-3156, I try to update my centos 7.9 with the following command :

```
yum update sudo*
```

But the command return the follwing :

```
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * atomic: www5.atomicorp.com
 * epel: mirror.hostnet.nl
No packages marked for update
```

I also try `yum clean all` but still the same result.

My Centos run Plesk. Plesk update don't fix issue, `sudo` still not update to unvulnerable version.

UPDATE

The only check I have done after update is the version and I expected to see a sudo in version 1.9.x, but it's still to 1.8.x I don't remeber the minor version is previously.
But it's updated, because when I do the test, the Segmentation fault message was gone.

```
sudoedit -s '\' `perl -e 'print "A" x 65536'`
```

and I get the following message expected:

```
usage: sudoedit [-AknS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-T timeout]
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the change log this patch is applied through a regular update:

```
2021-01-20 - Radovan Sroka <rsroka@redhat.com> - 1.8.23-10.1
- RHEL 7.9.Z ERRATUM
- CVE-2021-3156
Resolves: rhbz#1917729
```

Binary package [sudo-1.8.23-10.el7_9.1.x86_64.rpm](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-updates-x86_64/sudo-1.8.23-10.el7_9.1.x86_64.rpm.html) changelog.

Checking `sudo` vulnerability with the following command:

```
sudoedit -s /
```

**Patched** `sudo` versions should print the `usage`:

```
usage: sudoedit [-AknS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p
                prompt] [-T timeout] [-u user] file ...
```

**Vulnerable** `sudo` version should print:

```
sudoedit: /: not a regular file
```

Comment: thanks, it's fix during my update after 'yum clean all', I expected to see a version 1.9 but my base version is 1.8. When I do the test to exploit this CVE the troubble was gone.
`sudoedit -s '\' `perl -e 'print "A" x 65536'`

Comment: @Gusse I have updated my answer, please check it.

Comment: thanks ! I have edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, be aware that using unescaped asterisks may lead to shell expansion which could result in the exact issue you're experiencing.

Secondly, there's no need to use an asterisk at all, `yum update sudo` will perfectly suffice.

Thirdly, if you have other packages related to `sudo`, e.g. `sudo-logsrvd` then you could run `yum update 'sudo*'`.

Lastly, please report your sudo version via `rpm -q sudo`